# Как самостоятельно сделать анимацию SVG иконки

Tags: css, svg, css-animation, svg-animation

Требуется сделать векторную SVG иконку с анимацией на основе растрового образца.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1. Должны вращаться глаза
2. Язычок должен перемещаться справа-налево

Образец анимации:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать такую анимацию?

Answer (score 5):

### Пошаговая реализация рисования и анимации иконки

*Шаг #1. Загрузка в векторный редактор растрового изображения.*

Загружаем в векторный редактор растровое изображение иконки и наносим узловые точки по контурам рисунка.

С помощью рычагов управления узловыми точками, добиваемся полного совпадения формы кривых с оригиналом растрового образца.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*Шаг #2. Сохраняем файл в формате `*.svg`*

Для уменьшения знаков после запятой и удаления лишних строчек, которые оставляет векторный редактор, оптимизируем файл с помощью [SVGOMG](https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/)

Ниже получившийся код векторной иконки:

```html
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1"  width="450" height="450" viewBox="0 40 150 150">
              <!-- Контур иконки -->
  <path id="contour" d="M100 73.6a25.3 25.3 0 0 1-25.4 25.3 25.3 25.3 0 0 1-25.3-25.3 25.3 25.3 0 0 1 25.3-25.4 25.3 25.3 0 0 1 25.3 25.4z"   fill="#FFEEA3"  stroke="#C29653" stroke-width="3"  stroke-dasharray="none" />
              <!-- Правый глаз -->
  <path id="eye_right" d="M85 64c2.4 0 4.8 2.3 4.8 5.2 0 3-2.4 5.2-4.8 5.2s-4.8-2.2-5-5.3a5 5 0 0 1 5-5.1z"  fill="none" stroke="#C29653" stroke-width="2" />
   
                    <!-- Правый зрачок -->
  <path id="pupil-right" d="M82.7 66.7c1.1 0 2.3.9 2.3 2.5s-1.2 2.3-2.3 2.2c-1 0-1.9-1-1.9-2.2 0-1.3.9-2.5 2-2.5z"  fill="#36404D" stroke="#687B94" stroke-width="1" >
     
  </path>
             <!-- Левый глаз -->
  <path id="eye_left" d="M64 64c2.5 0 5.3 1.5 5.4 5.3 0 3-2.9 5.3-5.4 5.2-2.4 0-5-2.3-5-5.4a5 5 0 0 1 5-5z"  fill="none" stroke="#C29653" stroke-width="2"/>
               <!-- Левый зрачок -->
 <path id="pupil-left" d="M66.5 66.9c1.1 0 2.3.9 2.3 2.3s-1.2 2.4-2.3 2.4c-1.1 0-2.3-.7-2.3-2.5 0-1.6 1.3-2.2 2.3-2.2z"   stroke="#687B94" stroke-width="1"  >
     
  </path>
  
               <!-- Язык -->
   <g id="tongue" >
  <path  d="M75.8 85c0 1.1 1 3.4 1.6 5 .6 1.2 1 2.8 2.2 3.6 1.6 1 3.8 1.1 5.5.4 1-.4 1.8-1.5 2.3-2.5.5-1.3.7-2.7.6-4-.2-1.7-1-3-1.7-4.6-.3-.6-2.4.3-3.5.6-2 .6-6.9.2-7 1.6z"  fill="#F78F8F" stroke="#CA4C48" stroke-width="1" />
  <path d="M80.2 84.3c-.3.6.8 1 1 1.6.2.6 0 1.3 0 2 .1.3.1.7.3 1 .3.4.8 1 1.2.8.8-.3.7-1.6.7-2.4 0-.9-.2-1.8-.7-2.5a2 2 0 0 0-1.1-.8c-.5-.1-1.3-.1-1.4.3z"  fill="#CD4D4D"  stroke-width="1"  />  
    
 </g>    
       
                <!-- Рот -->
    <path id="mouth" d="M59 81.1s6.4 2.6 9.9 3c4.6.6 9.3.3 13.8-.6 2.4-.5 7-2.5 7-2.5"  fill="none" stroke="#C29653" stroke-width="2.5" stroke-linecap="round" />  
    <path id="trace" stroke="#C29653" d="m 64.036017,83.166226 c 0,0 6.966915,1.220923 10.487288,1.249571 0.984992,0.008 2.939618,-0.301827 2.939618,-0.301827" />
</svg>
```

*Шаг #3.  Анимация вращения глаз (зрачка)*

Добавляем к path анимацию:

```
                  <!-- Правый зрачок -->
  <path id="pupil-right" d="M82.7 66.7c1.1 0 2.3.9 2.3 2.5s-1.2 2.3-2.3 2.2c-1 0-1.9-1-1.9-2.2 0-1.3.9-2.5 2-2.5z" 
   fill="#36404D" stroke="#687B94" stroke-width="1" >
      <animateTransform id="an_right" attributeName="transform" type="rotate" 
  begin="contour.mouseenter" end="contour.mouseleave" dur="1s" 
  values="0, 85,69;360, 85,69" repeatCount="indefinite" /> 
  </path>
```

Анимация вращения зрачков начнется после наведения курсора на иконку:

```html
<svg id="contour" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1"  width="150" height="150" viewBox="45 45 60 60"  >
<defs>
<path id="trace" stroke="#C29653" d="m 64.036017,83.166226 c 0,0 6.966915,1.220923 10.487288,1.249571 0.984992,0.008 2.939618,-0.301827 2.939618,-0.301827" />
</defs>  
  <!-- Контур иконки -->
  <path id="contour" d="M100 73.6a25.3 25.3 0 0 1-25.4 25.3 25.3 25.3 0 0 1-25.3-25.3 25.3 25.3 0 0 1 25.3-25.4 25.3 25.3 0 0 1 25.3 25.4z"   fill="#FFEEA3"  stroke="#C29653" stroke-width="3"  stroke-dasharray="none" />
              <!-- Правый глаз -->
  <path id="eye_right" d="M85 64c2.4 0 4.8 2.3 4.8 5.2 0 3-2.4 5.2-4.8 5.2s-4.8-2.2-5-5.3a5 5 0 0 1 5-5.1z"  fill="none" stroke="#C29653" stroke-width="2" />
   
                    <!-- Правый зрачок -->
  <path id="pupil-right" d="M82.7 66.7c1.1 0 2.3.9 2.3 2.5s-1.2 2.3-2.3 2.2c-1 0-1.9-1-1.9-2.2 0-1.3.9-2.5 2-2.5z"  fill="#36404D" stroke="#687B94" stroke-width="1" >
     <animateTransform id="an_right" attributeName="transform" type="rotate" begin="contour.mouseenter" end="contour.mouseleave" dur="1s" values="0, 85,69;360, 85,69" repeatCount="indefinite" /> 
  </path>
             <!-- Левый глаз -->
  <path id="eye_left" d="M64 64c2.5 0 5.3 1.5 5.4 5.3 0 3-2.9 5.3-5.4 5.2-2.4 0-5-2.3-5-5.4a5 5 0 0 1 5-5z" fill="none" stroke="#C29653" stroke-width="2"/>
               <!-- Левый зрачок -->
 <path id="pupil-left" d="M66.5 66.9c1.1 0 2.3.9 2.3 2.3s-1.2 2.4-2.3 2.4c-1.1 0-2.3-.7-2.3-2.5 0-1.6 1.3-2.2 2.3-2.2z"  fill="#36404D" stroke="#687B94" stroke-width="1"  >
     <animateTransform id="an_left" attributeName="transform" type="rotate" begin="contour.mouseenter" end="contour.mouseleave" dur="1s" values="0, 64,69;360, 64,69" repeatCount="indefinite" /> 
  </path>
                 <!-- Рот -->
    <path id="mouth" d="M59 81.1s6.4 2.6 9.9 3c4.6.6 9.3.3 13.8-.6 2.4-.5 7-2.5 7-2.5"  fill="none" stroke="#C29653" stroke-width="2.5" stroke-linecap="round" />  
    
  
               <!-- Язык -->
   <g id="tongue" >
  <path  d="M75.8 85c0 1.1 1 3.4 1.6 5 .6 1.2 1 2.8 2.2 3.6 1.6 1 3.8 1.1 5.5.4 1-.4 1.8-1.5 2.3-2.5.5-1.3.7-2.7.6-4-.2-1.7-1-3-1.7-4.6-.3-.6-2.4.3-3.5.6-2 .6-6.9.2-7 1.6z"  fill="#F78F8F" stroke="#CA4C48" stroke-width="1" />
  <path d="M80.2 84.3c-.3.6.8 1 1 1.6.2.6 0 1.3 0 2 .1.3.1.7.3 1 .3.4.8 1 1.2.8.8-.3.7-1.6.7-2.4 0-.9-.2-1.8-.7-2.5a2 2 0 0 0-1.1-.8c-.5-.1-1.3-.1-1.4.3z"  fill="#CD4D4D"  stroke-width="1"  />  
    
 </g>    
 </svg>
```

*Шаг #4.  Анимация вращения языка*

```
             <!-- Язык -->
   <g id="tongue" transform="translate(-78 -84)">
  <path  d="M75.8 85c0 1.1 1 3.4 1.6 5 .6 1.2 1 2.8 2.2 3.6 1.6 1 3.8 1.1 5.5.4 1-.4 1.8-1.5 2.3-2.5.5-1.3.7-2.7.6-4-.2-1.7-1-3-1.7-4.6-.3-.6-2.4.3-3.5.6-2 .6-6.9.2-7 1.6z"  fill="#F78F8F" stroke="#CA4C48" stroke-width="1" />
  <path d="M80.2 84.3c-.3.6.8 1 1 1.6.2.6 0 1.3 0 2 .1.3.1.7.3 1 .3.4.8 1 1.2.8.8-.3.7-1.6.7-2.4 0-.9-.2-1.8-.7-2.5a2 2 0 0 0-1.1-.8c-.5-.1-1.3-.1-1.4.3z"  fill="#CD4D4D"  stroke-width="1"  />  
                  <!-- Анимация языка    -->
   <animateMotion begin="svg1.mouseenter" end="svg1.mouseleave" dur="1s" rotate="auto" additive="sum"
       keyPoints="0;1;0" keyTimes="0;0.5;1" calcMode="linear" repeatCount="indefinite" fill="freeze"    >
      <mpath xlink:href="#trace" />
    </animateMotion>    
 </g>
```

С помощью атрибутов `keyPoints="0;1;0"` `keyTimes="0;0.5;1"` `calcMode="linear"` реализуется перемещение языка в разные стороны

Собираем части кода в одном месте.
***При наведении будут работать анимации вращения зрачков и языка.***

```html
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1"  width="150" height="150" viewBox="45 45 60 60" >
<defs>
<path id="trace" stroke="#C29653" d="m 64.036017,83.166226 c 0,0 6.966915,1.220923 10.487288,1.249571 0.984992,0.008 2.939618,-0.301827 2.939618,-0.301827" />
</defs>  
  <!-- Контур иконки -->
  <path id="contour" d="M100 73.6a25.3 25.3 0 0 1-25.4 25.3 25.3 25.3 0 0 1-25.3-25.3 25.3 25.3 0 0 1 25.3-25.4 25.3 25.3 0 0 1 25.3 25.4z"   fill="#FFEEA3"  stroke="#C29653" stroke-width="3"  stroke-dasharray="none" />
              <!-- Правый глаз -->
  <path id="eye_right" d="M85 64c2.4 0 4.8 2.3 4.8 5.2 0 3-2.4 5.2-4.8 5.2s-4.8-2.2-5-5.3a5 5 0 0 1 5-5.1z"  fill="none" stroke="#C29653" stroke-width="2" />
   
                    <!-- Правый зрачок -->
  <path id="pupil-right" d="M82.7 66.7c1.1 0 2.3.9 2.3 2.5s-1.2 2.3-2.3 2.2c-1 0-1.9-1-1.9-2.2 0-1.3.9-2.5 2-2.5z" fill="#36404D" stroke="#687B94" stroke-width="1" >
     <animateTransform id="an_right" attributeName="transform" type="rotate" begin="svg1.mouseenter" end="svg1.mouseleave" dur="1s" values="0, 85,69;360, 85,69" repeatCount="indefinite" /> 
  </path>
             <!-- Левый глаз -->
  <path id="eye_left" d="M64 64c2.5 0 5.3 1.5 5.4 5.3 0 3-2.9 5.3-5.4 5.2-2.4 0-5-2.3-5-5.4a5 5 0 0 1 5-5z" fill="none" stroke="#C29653" stroke-width="2"/>
               <!-- Левый зрачок -->
 <path id="pupil-left" d="M66.5 66.9c1.1 0 2.3.9 2.3 2.3s-1.2 2.4-2.3 2.4c-1.1 0-2.3-.7-2.3-2.5 0-1.6 1.3-2.2 2.3-2.2z"  fill="#36404D" stroke="#687B94" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-opacity="1">
     <animateTransform id="an_left" attributeName="transform" type="rotate" begin="svg1.mouseenter" end="svg1.mouseleave" dur="1s" values="0, 64,69;360, 64,69" repeatCount="indefinite" /> 
  </path>
                 <!-- Рот -->
    <path id="mouth" d="M59 81.1s6.4 2.6 9.9 3c4.6.6 9.3.3 13.8-.6 2.4-.5 7-2.5 7-2.5" id="path852" fill="none" stroke="#C29653" stroke-width="2.5" stroke-linecap="round" />  
    
  
               <!-- Язык -->
   <g id="tongue" transform="translate(-78 -84)">
  <path  d="M75.8 85c0 1.1 1 3.4 1.6 5 .6 1.2 1 2.8 2.2 3.6 1.6 1 3.8 1.1 5.5.4 1-.4 1.8-1.5 2.3-2.5.5-1.3.7-2.7.6-4-.2-1.7-1-3-1.7-4.6-.3-.6-2.4.3-3.5.6-2 .6-6.9.2-7 1.6z"  fill="#F78F8F" stroke="#CA4C48" stroke-width="1" />
  <path d="M80.2 84.3c-.3.6.8 1 1 1.6.2.6 0 1.3 0 2 .1.3.1.7.3 1 .3.4.8 1 1.2.8.8-.3.7-1.6.7-2.4 0-.9-.2-1.8-.7-2.5a2 2 0 0 0-1.1-.8c-.5-.1-1.3-.1-1.4.3z"  fill="#CD4D4D"  stroke-width="1"  />  
                  <!-- Анимация языка    -->
   <animateMotion begin="svg1.mouseenter" end="svg1.mouseleave" dur="1s" rotate="auto" additive="sum"
       keyPoints="0;1;0" keyTimes="0;0.5;1" calcMode="linear" repeatCount="indefinite" fill="freeze"    >
      <mpath xlink:href="#trace" />
    </animateMotion>    
 </g>    
     
</svg>
```